# How to have multiple Main Executable files with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to package an office program in a setup file, and it has more than one (three to be be exact) main executables each which start your Word, Spreadsheet, and powerpoint software seperatly. Thanks

Comment: Ok, adding more shortcuts would work. Thanks

Comment: As TLama says - you may add as many as you want/need to. Script Wizard is only "helper" which can make it easier to create installer for the begginers.

Comment: I am using the Script Wizard, that was the problem, Thanks...

Comment: @RobeN, I've deleted my comments from here since this question is unanserable in its current state. There is no mention of script wizard, nor specified what the *main executable* is. Hence my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inno Setup itself has no concept of the "main executable". This only appears in the wizard for simplification.

Once the script has been created, you can install as many `[Files]` or `[Icons]` as you want for every "main executable".